# Querying similar but disjoint datasets in a single SQL query

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

In SQL (specifically MySQL, but the question is generic enough), what is the most efficient way to query time-series data when I have multiple tables across disjoint time ranges? For example, if my tables are as follows:

```
router1_20090330( unixtime integer unsigned, 
                  iface1_in integer unsigned,
                  iface1_out integer unsigned )
router1_20090331( unixtime integer unsigned, 
                  iface1_in integer unsigned,
                  iface1_out integer unsigned )
```

and so on, with (say) 1 minute samples of the in and out traffic on interface1, giving 86400 records per day table.

I want the query to represent something like

```
SELECT CAST(unixtime/3600 as unsigned) AS hour, 
       sum(iface1_in), sum(iface1_out) 
  from router1_20090330 *then* router1_20090331
  group by hour order by hour;
```

i.e. I would like both tables to be queried and aggregated, but one after the other instead of being joined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to UNION the two (or more) tables:

```
SELECT CAST(unixtime/3600 as unsigned) AS hour,
    SUM(iface1_in), SUM(iface1_out)
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM router1_20090330
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM router1_20090331
) x
GROUP BY hour
ORDER BY hour
```

Note that the "ALL" after UNION tells the query to keep duplicate rows (if the same values appear in both tables - unlikely in your scenario). I usually use UNION ALL because I think it avoids the overhead of testing the data for duplicate rows.

Comment: The union overhead is considerable, it's essentially a join on all columns

Comment: @Khb: That's not what a UNION is.  It's *appending* rows, not *joining* rows.

Comment: @Khb: Sorry, that's just not accurate.

Comment: @Bill, when the union is removing duplicate rows in the output, how do you think it does that?

Comment: @Khb: In a manner similar to the way DISTINCT works.  Many implementations sort the interim result to make it easy to eliminate duplicates.  This is *not* a join.